# How precise is "gegen 8 Uhr"?

Tags: usage, time

I often hear "dann treffen wir uns gegen 8 Uhr irgendwo". How precise is this? Is it ±5 min or ±10 min or does it depend on the situation?

Are there other words which means "approximately at eight", but are either less precise or more precise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It depends on the persons and situation.

In my opinion it is around ±5 min or ±10 min and it sounds to me if a group is meeting before 8 (maybe somewhere in the city or at an event) and the other person will join them later but without any fixed time

Comment: More precise: genau um 8. Less precise: irgendwann um 8, um 8 Uhr herum, ab 8

Comment: Note: the question if "gegen 8 Uhr" is *always before* 8 o'clock has been heavily discussed on various sites. Some argue that it's always before 8, others say it can be before or after 8.

Comment: I'm not so sure about the "always before" meaning. Although IMO the period which is accepted "after" a certain point of time is certainly shorter: You don't want to let people wait for you.
As a rule of thumb: -10/+5 minutes.

Comment: @0x6d4: that's exactly my point: there is no generally accepted interpretation. Some people are *very* sure that it's "always before" while others say "it's -10/+5" (or something similar) and a few say "it's ±10".

Comment: normally you divide the hour in 4 quarter so i assume maximal ±5 min as ok, 10 min is too close to 8h15min ... whats the point of saying "gegen 8 Uhr" at all when youre are not allowed to come later than 8?

Comment: I have to admit, I never thought of 'gegen 8 Uhr' to be valid only for times before 8 o'clock before (maybe because I tend to be late?). But now thinking about it, there is much sense, in only accepting times before 8 as valid. On the other hand: If I didn't knew it - how should others know? About the distance: Depends on the kind of termin. You might even say: "Wir gehen abends immer noch spazieren - meist bis gegen 7 oder gegen 8". This wouldn't mean either 18:55-19:00 or 19:55-20:00 Uhr, but maybe 18:30 to 20:00 Uhr.

Comment: *... depends on the person ...* - If the person is me it means +/- 15 minutes  :D

Answer (score 8):

It means *around*, *about* or *towards* the time. It's a rough time with some minutes tolerance, not important after the mentioned time or before it. (as [therealmarv has answered](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/how-precise-is-gegen-8-uhr/2094#2094)) it depends on the person.

**EDIT**

Other words which means "approximately at eight" (less to more precise*):

- so gegen acht Uhr
- ungefähr um acht Uhr
- gegen acht Uhr
- etwa um acht Uhr
- um acht Uhr oder so

If you mean the precise time you would say:

- um acht Uhr
- um genau acht/ genau um acht
- um Punkt acht Uhr

<sub>* : it's hard for the first five or so entries in the list to determine which one is more precise. At least colloquially, they can all mean the same.</sub>

Comment: +1 Gigili, this is nice addition to the previous answer, but I still accept the other one since it answers the question more directly.