# Was bedeutet genau "gegen 18 Uhr mit einem Essen enden"? Um 18 oder später?

Tags: meaning

Ich habe schon [diese Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/how-precise-is-gegen-8-uhr) gelesen, wo die Ungenauigkeit der Präposition *gegen* in betracht bezogen wurde. Trotzdem bin ich mir nicht so sicher, was der Text in Schrägschrift im folgenden Satz bedeutet:

> Die Konferenz wird am Montag, den 14.10, *gegen 18.00 Uhr mit einem gemeinsamen Essen enden*.

Gegen 18.00 Uhr

- endet die ganze Konferenz? oder
- fängt erst das gemeinsame Essen an?

---

Die Frage scheint dumm zu sein, jedoch kann es um eine für mich unbekannte Redewendung gehen. (Ich will keine falsche Fahrkarte kaufen.)

Comment: Nicht ganz eindeutig, würde ich sagen. Eigentlich eignet sich diese Formulierung nur für einen kurzen Programmpunkt (z.B. wenn Gruppenfotos gemacht werden sollen). Ansonsten sollte man eher schreiben: _Ab 18 Uhr lassen wir den Tag mit einem gemeinsamen Essen ausklingen_ o.ä. – Da kann man nur nachfragen.

Comment: Zur Sicherheit beantworte ich auch noch die Frage im Titel: "gegen 18h" heißt "um ungefähr 18h". Oder, wie meine amerikanischen Freunde sagen würden, "sixish".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rein intuitiv verstehe ich den Satz so: Die Konferenz selbst dauert bis ca. 18 Uhr. Anschließend findet ein gemeinsames Essen statt.

Die zweite Variante, dass das Essen um 18.00 Uhr endet, ist eher unwahrscheinlich, da der Text nicht explizit auf Beginn und Ende des Essens eingeht und da erfahrungsgemäß (meiner Erfahrung nach) nicht alle Konferenzteilnehmer am Essen teilnehmen.

Die Formulierung ist allerdings tatsächlich zweideutig.

Comment: Und die Dauer eines Essens in aller Regel auch schwer zu bestimmen ist. Ein Essen hat für gewöhnlich ein undefiniertes Ende.

Answer (score 10):

Ich würde sagen, die Unbestimmtheit liegt eher im Verb *(mit etwas) enden* und weniger an der Präposition *gegen*.

> Die Konferenz wird gegen 18:00 Uhr enden.

Trotz *gegen* ist hier der Endzeitpunkt klar. (*gegen* bedeutet *ungefähr, etwa, approximately*)

> Die Konferenz wird um 18:00 Uhr mit einem gemeinsamen Essen enden.

Hier wird *gegen* nicht verwendet, der Satz ist aber noch immer nicht eindeutig.

Answer (score 1):

Der Beispielsatz sagt aus, dass die Konferenz selbst ungefähr um 18 Uhr enden wird und dann das gemeinsame Essen begonnen wird. "Gegen" steht hierbei für eine ungefähre Zeitangabe, die sich noch ein wenig verschieben kann. Daher kann das gemeinsame Essen auch um 18.10 Uhr beginnen, 18 Uhr ist nur ein ungefährer Wert.