# Gegen 15:00 Uhr ... kann es auch kurz nach 15:00 umfassen?

Tags: word-usage, regional

Wenn *ich* jemandem sage, daß ich **gegen fünfzehn Uhr** komme, dann meine ich damit, daß ich spätestens 15:00 Uhr da bin, eigentlich eher etwas überpünktlich.

Die Bedeutung habe ich als Kind so kennengelernt und wende es auch heute noch so an. Das erschloß sich mir auch immer indem ich statt der Zeit etwas Gegenständliches einsetzte. Beispielsweise den Spaten gegen die Wand stellen.

Meine Frage ist nun folgende. Bekannte von mir benutzen **gegen** im obigen Zusammenhang als Ersatz für **etwa** oder **zirka**. In deren Sprachverständnis umfaßt **gegen** also auch kurz nach der besagten Zeit. Diese Verwendung war mir bis vor einiger Zeit überhaupt nicht geläufig und ich frage mich daher, ob es sich um eine lokale Sprachvariante handelt (hier ganz Norden Deutschlands)? Kann da jemand weiterhelfen?

Comment: Ich verwende im Südwesten Deutschlands "gegen" ebenfalls im Sinne von "etwa, circa", Bekannte tun es ebenfalls und es wird allgemein verstanden.

Comment: related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/was-bedeutet-genau-gegen-18-uhr-mit-einem-essen-enden-um-18-oder-sp%c3%a4ter and (in English) https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2093/how-precise-is-gegen-8-uhr

Comment: @IQV: interessantes Detail, die besagten ,aus dem Norden stammenden, Bekannten wohnen seit deutlich über einem Jahrzehnt im Südwesten Deutschlands. Vielleicht haben sie es also auch dort  aufgesammelt. Wobei ja nicht jede mundartliche Wortverwendung hochsprachlich korrekt ist. Daher auch meine Frage. Im Süden Deutschlands wird beispielsweise häufig "wie" statt "als" verwendet.

Comment: Auch ich komme aus dem Süden (Baden  Württemberg) und bei uns ist "gegen" ebenfalls mit "kurz vorher oder kurz nachher" belegt und eben NICHT auf kurz vorher beschränkt...

Comment: Die Bedeutung "etwa, ungefähr" ist jedenfalls so standardsprachlich, dass sie den Einzug in Duden gefunden hat. Wenn du eine andere Verständnis hast, ist das vermutlich eher die lokale Sprachvariante: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gegen_etwa_circa

Comment: Interessante Frage. Ich kannte die Bedeutung *»definitiv davor, auf keinen Fall danach«* gar nicht. (siehe auch meine Antwort)

Comment: Ganz klarer Fall in Mitteldeutschland: "Gegen" heißt kurz davor bis zum Zeitpunkt. Stimmt hier mit der Duden-Definition überein https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/gegen%20%5Bzeitlich%5D

Comment: @jarnbjo: Das ist kein überzeugendes Argument. Allgemein sind die Synonymlisten bei duden.de nicht symmetrisch, was bereits andeutet, dass es sich hier nicht um absolute Synonyme handelt, sondern eines der sogenannten Synonyme durchaus eine breitere Bedeutung (hier: vor und nach dem genannten Zeitpunkt) als das andere (hier: nur vor dem bzw. spätestens zum genannten Zeitpunkt) haben kann. Konkret führt Duden als Synonyme zu [circa](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/circa) unter anderem auch "beinahe" und "fast" auf, welche *im Standardfall* wohl unzweifelhaft eine Annäherung an einen ...

Comment: ... größeren Wert von unten ausdrücken (sofern also aus dem Kontext nicht direkt eine andere "Bewegungsrichtung" klar wird). Eben genau, wie dies auch bei "gegen" der Fall ist, denn die Zeit verläuft insbesondere im Alltagsgebrauch nun mal vorwärts.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Ich weiß nicht warum du dich auf die Synonymliste beschränkst. Die von mir zitierte Bedeutung von "gegen" als Adverb findest du im Abschnitt "Bedeutungsübersicht".

Comment: @äüö finde ich ja spannend, daß der Duden zwei - eigentlich gegensätzliche ("zur Angabe eines ungefähren Zeitpunktes, der unter- oder überschritten werden kann" vs. "zur Angabe eines bestimmten Zeitraumes, der nicht überschritten wird") - Bedeutungserklärungen gibt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Österreich (Sicher: Steiermark, Burgenland, Wien, Niederösterreich. Vermutlich aber auch darüber hinaus):

Der Satz

> Ich werde gegen 15:00 Uhr bei dir sein.

bedeutet hier:

> Meine Reiseplanung zielt darauf ab, dass ich pünktlich um 15:00 Uhr bei dir eintreffen werde. Ich habe aber nicht auf alle Parameter meiner Reise Einfluss, daher kann es sein, dass ich auch etwas früher **oder auch etwas später** ankomme.

Anders Beispiel:

> Laut Augenzeugen verließ Frau Schober das Lokal gegen 23:30 Uhr.

heißt:

> Keiner der Augenzeugen hat genau beim Abgang von Frau Schober auf die Uhr geschaut. Aus den Angaben der Augenzeugen kann man aber zusammenfassend schließen, dass es ungefähr halb zwölf gewesen sein muss als sie das Lokal verließ, **plus**/minus 5 bis 10 Minuten.

---

Darüberhinaus möchte ich anmerken, dass *»pünktlich«* bedeutet: *»genau zur vereinbarten Uhrzeit«*, wobei je nach Situation noch wenige Minuten Abweichung in beide Richtungen toleriert werden.

Wer deutlich vor der vereinbarten Zeit kommt, ist **nicht** pünktlich, sondern zu früh, also *unpünktlich!* (Ein Bus, der eine Haltestelle 2 Minuten vor dem im Fahrplan angegebenen Zeitpunkt verlässt, ist nicht pünktlich. Besucher, die am Sonntag statt wie vereinbart um 11:00 Uhr schon um 10:30 an der Tür klingeln, sind nicht pünktlich.)

Comment: "Wer deutlich vor der vereinbarten Zeit kommt, ist **nicht** pünktlich, sondern zu früh, also *unpünktlich*!" - das hängt aber komplett davon ab, ob sich "pünktlich sein" auf das Eintreffen oder die Anwesenheit bezieht. Wer zu früh kommt, mag unpünktlich eintreffen, ist aber dennoch pünktlich anwesend, da im letzten Fall "pünktlich" effektiv gleichbedeutend mit "rechtzeitig eingetroffen" ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Du verwechselst *pünktlich* mit *rechtzeitig*. Diese beiden Begriffe sind keine Synonyme!

Comment: Eigentlich hatte ich in meinem Kommentar doch exakt dargestellt, in welchem Verhältnis die beiden Begriffe zueinander stehen.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Du hast exakt dargestellt, in welchem Verhältnis die beiden Begriffe **aus deiner Sicht** stehen. Ich habe in meinem Kommentar versucht darzustellen, dass deine Sicht unzutreffend ist. Anders gesagt: Du irrst dich. Wenn meine Eltern 90 Minuten vor der vereinbarten Zeit eintreffen, also zu einem Zeitpunkt wo ich noch im Bett liege (was tatsächlich schon mal passiert ist), dass sind sie zwar zum vereinbarten Zeitpunkt auch noch bei mir in der Wohnung, deswegen aber noch lange nicht pünktlich, sondern viel zu früh, also unpünktlich, was ich als grobe Unhöflichkeit empfinde.

Answer (score 2):

Also hier im **Westen** (NRW) wird *gegen* bei einer Zeitbeschreibung auch als Variante von 'etwa', 'ungefähr' und ähnlichem benutzt.

Es ist relativ ungenau und wird vor allem benutzt wenn die Ankunftszeit nicht genau eingeschätzt werden kann, etwa bei einer langen Anreise.

Meiner Erfahrung sind +/- 5-10 Minuten um die genannte Uhrzeit mit der Aussage **gegen** abgedeckt. Bei größerer Verspätung sollte man Bescheid geben.

Comment: Gegen Ostern beginnt die Spargelsaison - +/- 10 Minuten.

Comment: @userunknown: Die Frage bezog sich auf Uhrzeiten. *Ostern* ist keine Uhrzeit.

Comment: @userUnknown: Auch hier passt 'gegen' für 'ungefähr'... Die Toleranz wird hier aber nicht in Minuten, sondern Tagen gesehen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Die Frage bezieht sich erkennbar auf Zeiten, auch wenn als konkretes Beispiel dann eine Uhrzeit verwendet wurde. Gegen 2050 wirst Du mir Recht geben.

Answer (score 1):

Hier in Baden-Württemberg bezeichnet *gegen* meiner Erfahrung nach ausschließlich die Zeit *kurz vor* der genannten Uhrzeit. Das passt auch mit der exakteren der von [Wiktionary](https://de.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/gegen) vorgeschlagenen Umschreibungen "in Richtung auf" zusammen - nur, wenn man sich (auf dem Zeitstrahl, in Richtung des Zeitverlaufs) noch auf den genannten Zeitpunkt zubewegt, geht man ihm ja noch "entgegen".

Sicher gibt es auch mal Situationen, in denen jemand ankündigt, "gegen zwei" da zu sein, dann aber erst ein paar Minuten nach zwei ankommt. Diese Person ist dann aber eben (in Bezug auf ihre Aussage) einfach unpünktlich beziehungsweise hat sich verspätet, während sie mit der Aussage "ungefähr um zwei" noch pünktlich gewesen wäre.

Interessanterweise scheint die exakte angegebene Uhrzeit ebenfalls von dem mit "gegen X Uhr" bezeichneten Zeitraum abgedeckt zu sein, was "gegen" synonym zu "spätestens um, wenn auch nicht bedeutend früher als" macht.

Comment: Das würde erklären warum die Schwaben immer so pünktlich sind.
Ihr habt einfach ein andere Definition von 'gegen' :D